# How to parse xml containing namespace through JAXB

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb

I am trying to parse an xml through JAXB which contains xmlns attribute. If I parse the xml as such it shows `NullPointerException`. But if I remove namespace tags and xmlns attributes then it worked fine. Sample xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<database xmlns="http://www.Example/Database" xmlns:layout="http://www.Example/Layouter">
    <namespace name="X1">
        <layout:record name="My_Layout" src="screen1.layout" />
    </namespace>

    <LayoutGroup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" LayoutGroupID="ID_1">
    </LayoutGroup>
</database>
```

and my sample code is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "database")
public class database {

    private LayoutGroup layoutGrp;

    @XmlElement(name = "LayoutGroup")
    public void setLayoutGrp(LayoutGroup gp) {
        layoutGrp = gp;
    }

    public LayoutGroup getLayoutGroup() {
        return layoutGrp;
    }

}
```

Another class:

```
@XmlRootElement (name="LayoutGroup")
public class LayoutGroup {

    String id;
    @XmlAttribute (name="LayoutGroupID")
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here's my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    database db = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("./res/test.xml"),database.class);
    System.out.println("Layout id is: "+db.getLayoutGroup().getId());
}
```

Could anyone please help to parse the original xml?

Comment: The following will help with JAXB and namespaces:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you're feeding your class an XML scoped with a namespace, you should also declare it in your receiving class.

Add this line on top of your class:

```
@XmlRootElement (name="database") 
@XmlType(namespace="http://www.Example/Database")
public class Database {
```

If it still gives an error, try adding the namespace definition in your LayoutGroup element and see if it works:

```
@XmlElement (name="LayoutGroup", namespace="http://www.Example/Database")
public void setLayoutGrp(LayoutGroup gp)
{
    layoutGrp = gp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried both the solutions but still it gives NullPointerException.

Comment: Can u share the exception stacktrace in the question?

Comment: Sorry if my questions is a silly one. I just want to parse the above xml through JAXB but I am getting an error. I dont know why exactly xmlns and xmlns:layout in above xml is used for and if I have to pare such an xml then how should I go about.